# Batch script removed the first 6 lines of all cvs files

Tags: csv, batch-file

I tried a few solutions here, but I wasn`t able to get a solution.
Short summary what it needs to do:

I have a lot ov CSV files and the first 6 lines included header information. I want to create a batch to delete the first lines for all CSV files.

Comment: `more +6 infile.csv > outfile.csv`. (Attention: `more` converts TABs to spaces). Put a `for` loop around to process "a lot of files" (see `for /?`)

Comment: Thank you for the fast feedback. Is there any way to cut the lines without tabs?

Comment: `find /v "  " infile.csv > outfile.csv` (with a TAB between the quotes) removes every line that contains a TAB

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.